# symfony doctrine entity database prevent an duplicite content

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, entity, duplicates

Hi i selected some data from DB but i see there a duplicite content... IT SHOULD'T be there!

So my question is easy:

how can i remove all duplicited content?

+

how can i set keys that this will not happen again:

http://www.upnito.sk/0/wcz6ffyacg5pr6kpzugd4wdt5rfps9nd.png

BTW: there can be 37 25, 37 38, 37 37, 37 40... there only CAN'T BE the image situation.

THX!

Comment: Use unique constraints for unique fields / lists of fields. A unique constraint will stop this from happening. Otherwise, the solutions in php and so on require extra overhead, and is better to leave this for the database to handle.

Comment: hm yes i know, but how can i set unique for two colums like and no for each of them extra? + i think it will threw me an error because in DB are already data like that right?

Comment: The other way of doing it would be to select everything and compute manually the unique values, which is a no-go. Yes, the database will issue a error, but it's a catchable error and will allow you to do something for that case. A unique key can be set for 2+ columns without a problem and the check using the index inside the database engine is alot faster than whatever you will ever manage to do.

Comment: And remember that sometimes it happens when you have some exceptions before flushing entities managed by `entity manager`

Comment: still didn't figure out how do it :/ can't i do it with mysql somehow? some great script to delete these rows? And then i would set an unique key